# Change icon on click while expanding div container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am testing/tweaking out Jquery slideToggle using the guide from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle). I want to change the + icon to - icon when the div`Panel` is expanded. Could someone guide me to correct path.

I am wondering something like in this website: http://www.serenahotels.com/en/default.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(".panel").slideToggle("normal");
        $(".flip").toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle')
    });
});
```

```css
.panel, .flip {
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

.flip:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
}


.panel {
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">I am hidden.</div>
 
<div class="flip"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to toggle [**FontAwesome**](https://fontawesome.com) icons. Instead of setting your initial `plus` sign in the `:after` pseudo-class for `.flip`, you'll want to instead give it a **default** class of `fa` and `fa-plus`. In addition to this, the classes `fa-plus-circle` and `fa-minus-circle` aren't valid FontAwesome classes; use `fa-plus` and `fa-minus` instead for your jQuery `.toggleClass()`.

Note that now that the icon is on `.flip` rather than on the `:after`, if you want to horizontally center it you will need to give it a `width` of `100%`. This also means you will `box-sizing: border-box` to prevent scrollbars... though you'll want this on all of your elements anyway.

This can all be seen in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    $(".panel").slideToggle("normal");
    $(".flip").toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus')
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">I am hidden.</div>

<div class="flip fa fa-plus"></div>
```

Don't forget to reference the FontAwesome library!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine now. Is there a way to control the icon size? 'fa-lg' doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @MohammadAhmed -- Yes! You're looking for the `fa-2x`, `fa-3x`, `fa-4x` and `fa-5x` classes :)